# Fibration of simplicial complexes

Tags: general-topology, simplicial-complex

I recently came across an unusual definition of fibration between simplicial complexes, and I need help to understand it (or possibly find a reference that can help me).

Before giving the definition, I shall recall some of the basic concepts involved:

- Given a simplicial map $f:\Gamma\rightarrow\Sigma$, the *image* of $f$ is the subcomplex $\mbox{im}(f)$ of $\Sigma$ defined by
  $$
  \mbox{im}(f):=\{f^\rightarrow \gamma\mid\gamma\in\Gamma\},
  $$
  where $f^\rightarrow\gamma:=\{f(v)\mid v\in\gamma\}$.
- A simplicial map $f:\Gamma\rightarrow\Sigma$ is a *simplicial quotient* if $\mbox{im}(f)=\Sigma$.
- Given an abstract simplicial complex $\Sigma$, the *(open) star* of a face $\sigma\in \Sigma$ is defined by $$\mbox{St}_\Sigma(\sigma):=\{\tau\in \Sigma\mid\sigma\subseteq\tau\}.$$
  The *closed star* of $\sigma$ is defined by 
  $$
  \overline{\mbox{St}}_\Sigma(\sigma):=\{\tau\in\Sigma\mid\sigma\cup\tau\in\Sigma\}
  $$
  which is analogous to the definition of the neighborhood of a vertex in a graph.
- Every simplicial map $f:\Gamma\rightarrow\Sigma$ induces a *local* simplicial map: given a face $\gamma\in\Gamma$, define
  $$
  f_\gamma:\overline{\mbox{St}}_\Gamma(\gamma)\rightarrow\overline{\mbox{St}}_\Sigma(f^\rightarrow\gamma)::\tau\mapsto \bigcup_{v\in \tau}f(v).
  $$

**Definition**
A simplicial map $f:\Gamma\rightarrow \Sigma$ between abstract simplicial complexes is said to be a *local quotient* if the maps $f_\gamma$ are all simplicial quotients. If, moreover, $f$ is also a simplicial quotient, it is called a *fibration map*.

**Questions**
My questions are the following:

- Why is this object called a fibration? In topology, fibrations are maps satisfying the homotopy lifting property. Does this `simplicial fibration' verify any analogous property?
- Would the geometric realization of such a map be a fibration in a
  topological sense?
- Simplicial complexes do not have enough structure for the definition of homotopy groups. The usual notion of simplicial fibration is the one of *Kan fibration* which involves simplicial sets. Is there a connection between these two concepts?
- Where can I find a reference explaining this definition in detail?